# Spark SQL databricks Create Table using CSV Options Documentation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-notebooks

Do you know where is the proper documentation for Spark SQL using databricks?

For example I wish to know the full options list for creating a table using csv in Azure databricks notebook.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any error you are facing? If yes add those details.

Comment: This might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using

Comment: @JayashankarGS, No, I am not facing any problem, but was looking generally for any detailed documentation, where it explains all the options for creating table using csv with examples. The docs on Apache Spark just mentions some of the options but not all with smaples.

Comment: @AvishekBhattacharya, thanks for the link. I came across this when googled before. But this does not describe the options like "inferschema", "header" etc. Some people just answer to some kind of specific questions for other users on for example stackoverflow. 
Until now I have not been able to find any comprehensive documention.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options available to read CSV file in databricks but there are no specific documents for that which options are supported for which file.

| **Property Name** | **Values** |
| --- | --- |
| Header | true/false |
| Inferschema | true/false |
| delimiter | , |
| quote | " |
| nullValue |  |

These options are similar to the [features](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features) given in this document and similar to those documented in the [pyspark CSV files](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#csv-files).